# How to get error logs from samsung remote tabs

Tags: android, performance, samsung-mobile, samsung-touchwiz

My android app is working fine on other mobiles, however it crashes on samsung devices. I can not manage a samsung device, so i downloaded the virtual device from samsung remote test lab.
My app crashes, but I don't know how to get the log cat errors, so that I can start debugging.